# My villager has disappeared he was in a one by two area and I don’t know what happened

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My villager has disappeared he was in a 1 x 2 area and I don’t know what happened So I logged onto my survival world And I had a store that I built for a villager he wasn’t in it but last night he was and I checked out the original village he was from and he wasn’t there I’m so mad please tell me how to fix this and he was only villager

Comment: And now my XP is gone I started at level one but when I logged on last night I had 29

Comment: Sounds like you died. Did someone else use your computer? Also, there are multiple different bugs that could have caused your villager to disappear. It's actually surprisingly difficult to ensure that this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Zombies can hit villagers through corners. If your area looked like this from the top down then a zombie most likely killed it.

```
 ■ 
■ ■
 ■
```